# Snowflake - Drop all Foreign Keys in Schema, possibly using CTE to delete

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know I can do the below command it will drop the FK's for that table but I want to make sure all FK's have been dropped in all tables based on a schema:

```
ALTER TABLE fk_table DROP FOREIGN KEY (fk_column);
```

If there isn't an easier way I found if I run the below it will show me all FK's created for a schema, but then how do I delete everything found in the results below:

```
select fk_tco.table_schema as foreign_schema,
       fk_tco.table_name as foreign_table,
       fk_tco.constraint_name as foreign_constraint,
       '>-' as rel,
       pk_tco.table_schema as referenced_schema,
       pk_tco.table_name as referenced_table,
       pk_tco.constraint_name as referenced_constraint
from information_schema.referential_constraints rco
join information_schema.table_constraints fk_tco 
     on fk_tco.constraint_name = rco.constraint_name
     and fk_tco.constraint_schema = rco.constraint_schema
join information_schema.table_constraints pk_tco
     on pk_tco.constraint_name = rco.unique_constraint_name
     and pk_tco.constraint_schema = rco.unique_constraint_schema
where pk_tco.table_schema = 'SCHEMA_TO_DELETE_IN'     
order by fk_tco.table_schema,
         fk_tco.table_name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating ALTER statement to remove foreign keys:

```
select 'ALTER TABLE ' || fk_tco.table_schema || '.' || fk_tco.table_name ||
       ' DROP CONSTRAINT "' || fk_tco.constraint_name || '";' AS alter_query
from information_schema.referential_constraints rco
join information_schema.table_constraints fk_tco 
     on fk_tco.constraint_name = rco.constraint_name
     and fk_tco.constraint_schema = rco.constraint_schema
join information_schema.table_constraints pk_tco
     on pk_tco.constraint_name = rco.unique_constraint_name
     and pk_tco.constraint_schema = rco.unique_constraint_schema
where pk_tco.table_schema = 'SCHEMA_TO_DELETE_IN'     
order by fk_tco.table_schema,
         fk_tco.table_name;
```

The generated alter_query should be copied into worksheet and run. If the goal is to have more "automatic" approach then it should be wrapped with stored procedure.

---

Sidenote: Foreign keys are NOT enforced on Snowflake. It means that is possible to:

```
CREATE TABLE t(id INT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE x(col TEXT, id INT REFERENCES t(id));

INSERT INTO x(col, id) VALUES ('a', 1); -- please note t is empty!
```

If the goal of foreign key removal is to improve perfromance there is no gain from that operation.

Related: [Supported Constraint Types](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constraints-overview.html#supported-constraint-types)

Comment: thank you for responding! when I run this statement the foreign key is instead showing the constraint value, so the rows look like this and show me an error when I try to run: ALTER TABLE my_table DROP FOREIGN KEY ('SYS_CONSTRAINT_da8-b490b-43490a-934a5-e63453e462b');      Also what do you mean by they are not enforced in Snowflake

Comment: @KristiLuna By not enforced it means they have purely informational role for data modelling. As for the second, yest the alter statement should be copied into worksheet and run - efectively dropping the FK.

Comment: when I run the query you wrote it shows the foreign keys as ('SYS_CONSTRAINT_da8-b490b-43490a-934a5-e63453e462b') which is not the foreign key column name so I see an error "INVALID IDENTIFIER" because that is not the foreign key column name

Comment: @KristiLuna Fixed, it should be DROP CONSTRAINT <name>